# Get local Dropbox path with Delphi XE7

Tags: json, delphi, base64, delphi-xe

I've put together a function in Delphi XE7 which returns the Dropbox directory path on my machine, as this path can be customized by the user.

This function currently works on my computer, but it could have many defects preventing it to work for other users on different machines. So I would be very grateful if anybody could point to these defects.

```
uses
  System.IOUtils, System.JSON, System.NetEncoding, JclSysInfo, JclStrings

function GetDropboxPath: string;
var
  tempstr: string;
  function ParseJsonStr(jStr, jPar1, jPar2: string): string; 
  var
    jObj: TJSONObject;
    jVal: TJSONValue;
  begin
    Result:= '';
    jObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(jStr) as TJSONObject;
    try
      jVal:= jObj.Get(jPar1).JsonValue;
      Result:= TJSONObject(jVal).Get(jPar2).JsonValue.Value;
    finally
      jObj.Free;
    end;
  end;
begin
  Result := '';
  tempstr := IncludeTrailingBackslash(JclSysInfo.GetAppdataFolder) + 'Dropbox\'; 
  if DirectoryExists(tempstr) then
  begin    
    if FileExists(tempstr + 'info.json') then // try with info.json
    begin
      tempstr := tempstr + 'info.json';
      tempstr := System.IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllText(tempstr);
      try
        tempstr := ParseJsonStr(tempstr, 'personal', 'path');
      except
        // Todo: log this error
        EXIT;
      end;
      Result := Trim(tempstr);
    end    
    else if FileExists(tempstr + 'host.db') then // else try with host.db
    begin
      tempstr := tempstr + 'host.db';
      tempstr := Trim(JclStrings.StrTrimCharLeft(System.IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllText(tempstr), '0'));
      Result := Trim(TNetEncoding.Base64.Decode(tempstr)); // needs XE7
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The result of the subroutine `ParseJsonStr`could be an empty string. In this case the `host.db` file should be checked, which currently is not the case because of the `if-else` structure. So instead of the `if-else` structure at the end of the `info.json` check, the result should be evaluated. Only in the case (and only then) it is empty, the second check of the `host-db` file should be executed. What do you think?

Comment: Also, in the `except` section, there should be no `EXIT` but instead it should continue to the `host.db` check. What do you think?

Comment: Personally, I would be reading that path from the registry.  Any user can install DropBox wherever he wants to. I doubt that you can rely on `JclSysInfo.GetAppdataFolder` (and, even if it works for DropBox, because they hard code some stuff, instead of following MS rules & allowing a choice, it is not guaranteed to work for all (read "properly coded") apps).

Comment: @Mawg From where in the Registry would you read it?

Comment: Google is your friend (or you could even just fire up Regedit & search for DropBox).  See http://forensicartifacts.com/2011/07/dropbox-config-files-windows/  or http://www.forensicfocus.com/Content/pid=429/page=2/ or any of the other numerous results of googling for `dropbox registry keys`

Comment: The path is not stored in Registry. The links you have posted clearly show it.